# Inno setup forward slashes instead of back slashes

Tags: inno-setup, backslash

I have to make a Inno Setup script to write to the registry the {app} path with forward slashes instead of backslashes

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"; ValueType:string; ValueName:"APP_HOME"; ValueData:"{app}"; Flags: preservestringtype
```

How to get {app} value with forward slashes (inno by default write it with backslashes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make a custom function for a [`{code:}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) scripted constant, e.g. this way:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "APP_HOME"; ValueData: {code:GetRegistryData}; Flags: preservestringtype

[Code]
function GetRegistryData(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := ExpandConstant('{app}');
  StringChangeEx(Result, '\', '/', True);
end;
```

Comment: I didn't find {code:*} syntax documentantion in the manual, thank you very much.